# Using a While loop and FindRoot

Tags: while-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I want to use a While loop and the FindRoot function to estimate a root.

```
`xroot = FindRoot[x Cos[x] == 0, {x, 2}];
itercnt == 0;
iterlimit == 10000;
While[f[x] > 10^{-5} && itercnt < iterlimit,
    x - f[x]/f'[x]; itercnt++]`
```

I can do it once but I want to do any amount of times. So please give constructive criticism of my code and how it can be simpler.

Comment: Hi Mike.  This question might be good for stackoverflow, or it might be more appropriate for the Code Review site here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `10^{-5}` should be `10^(-5)` or even just `10^-5` because `{}` and `()` mean completely different things to Mathematica. Next, I assume you are wanting to hunt for x near the root, but you do not appear to be changing the value of x in the loop and it looks like it will just repeat the same calculation over and over until you reach your loop count limit. Do you perhaps mean to change the value of x with each iteration like this `x=x-f[x]/f'[x]` to implement Newton's method?

Comment: `Clear[f,x];
f[x_]:=x*Cos[x];
xroot=FindRoot[f[x]==0,{x,2}];
Print[xroot];
itercnt=0;
iterlimit=10;
x=1.0;
While[Abs[f[x]]>10^-5&&itercnt<iterlimit,
Print[{x,f[x]}];x=x-f[x]/f'[x];itercnt++]` Study each of those changes very carefully and look up needed information in the help system until you understand exactly why each of those changes were made.